# create array from response data using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

```
function LoadSuppliers() {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/supplier/getSupplier',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        
          var result = response.data.result;
          console.log(result);

        
        }, error: function(data) {
          console.log('something went wrong!');
        }
    });
```

This is my loadSupplier function and I want to get these response data into a array and set to input field for autocomplete.. How can I Make a array here..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: 1. Which autocomplete? jQuery UI? 2. Post an example of the response - if the AJAX works, you can make an example WITHOUT the ajax which will run in a snippet here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parameter "dataType".

```
dataType: "JSON",
```

So in case that you are getting JSON response, you can do the following as;

```
function LoadSuppliers() {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/supplier/getSupplier',
        success: function(response) {
          var result = JSON.Parse(response);
          var result_array = [];
            for (const key in result) {
               result_array.push(result[key]); /// array with no key
                 //if you want to get JSON array,
                 let temp = {};
                 if (!result_array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     temp[key] = [];
                  }
                 temp[key].push(result[key]); /// JSON Array
                 result_array.push(temp);
             }
          
          console.log(result_array);
        
        }, error: function(data) {
          console.log('something went wrong!');
        }
    });
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can JSON.parse() to convert json response to JS object. then convert JS object to array

```
var yourArray = $.map(JSON.parse(response), function(value, index){
        return [value];
    });
```